# "has been effected" or "has been affected"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

For some reason I'm really struggling with this one... Here's the sentence that I found it in:

**"We'll start you off with a free identity theft scan to see if your good name has already been affected."**

Sentence can't be reworded, I just need to make sure it's the right usage of affect/effect.

Comment: Looking up the two words in any decent dictionary should answer your question. What is it you are unsure of, exactly? And what steps have you taken to try to answer the question before asking here? These are details that ***must*** be included in your question.